# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: Differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus

I am given the following question:

Let the function $F$ be defined as $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$ , where $f$ is continuous on all real numbers and $x \in [0,\infty). $

It is a multiple choice question and one of the possible answers goes as following: The function $F$ is differentiable.

I am not sure if this answer is correct when it is not specified on which interval the function $F$ is differentiable.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: If it is not specified, $F$ is differentiable means it is differentiable on its entire domain, which is $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Consider the right handed derivative at 0